# Adding Term store as a left navigation in Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, term-store, metadata-navigation

I have created a term store for a Sharepoint online Site collection and Added to the left navigation bar using the Navigation function under Look and feel in Site settings. 
currently, it is showing as follow, but what I really want to display only the top level of the term store eg - I want to Show only the Teams, not the second level "Adding Guest Users, Creating a Team"
Much better if I can allow them to drill down to the second level rather than showing the second level initially. 
Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I used this nice Tutorial https://support.office.com/en-us/article/enable-managed-navigation-for-a-site-in-sharepoint-49a067dc-77d2-455d-9e77-250ec7cc0a6d

**In short:**

SiteSettings->Navigation->Managed-Navigation-> Managed Navigation: Term Set->OK

Best from Cologne

Comment: Hi, I have done this without issue, my question is how we display only the top level of the term set, currently, it showing all levels.